# How to populate tableviews from UIViewController

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I want to add 4 UITableViews on my scrollview and poppulate them with some different arrays(let's say i have one array for each). I have added this scrollview too to my `self.view`(i do this stuff on a UIViewController class). How can i populate my Tableviews can anyone help please?

**Some More Details:**

here is a screen shot;
[image]

Here is the interface of my UIViewControllerClass

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainMenu : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *group1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *group2;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *group3;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *group4;

@end//i drag/dropped from IB, so there is no problem with synthesizes..
```

I want to populate these tableview with different arrays, how to handle this situation..? Thanks a lot

Additional Note; i tried something like this but no effect:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [group1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"tree", nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: You did not enter the dataSource in the interface and you must also implement the method: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dude, first you will make the uiviewcontroller de delegate and data source of all 4 tables, after that you will assign a different tag for each table.. and then you will add the delegate and datasource protocols... and the you will implement the datasource and delegate methods like a normal uitableviewcontroller... all these methods receive a Uitableview parameter, so you will test the tag of this table view like:

```
...

if (tableView.tag == 10) {
//implement the table 1
NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"tree", nil];
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

} else if (tableView.tag == 20) {
//implement the table 2
} else if (tableView.tag == 30) {
//implement the table 3
} else if (tableView.tag == 40) {
//implement the table 4
}

return cell;
```

this way you will use the same method to do all the table views..

Comment: but how to implement - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
} it doesnt accept switch()-case..

Comment: i solved the problem, it has been a lot(i used the tags as you said)